# Bokeh server + reverse-proxying with Nginx gives 404

Tags: python, nginx, proxy, bokeh

I'm trying to set up a Bokeh server and reverse proxy it with Nginx.

My p-website.conf now looks like:

```
server {
listen   80;
server_name  website.com;
client_max_body_size 25M;
access_log  /var/www/logs/p-website.access.nginx.log;
error_log  /var/www/logs/p-website.error.nginx.log error;
root    /var/www/pydocs/website/production/src;

include global/restrictions.conf;


location /plot/ {
    proxy_pass http://website.com:5100;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_buffering off;
}

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    # enable this if and only if you use HTTPS, this helps Rack
    # set the proper protocol for doing redirects:
    # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_connect_timeout 10;
    proxy_read_timeout 60s;

    proxy_pass http://production_website_gunicorn;
}
}
```

On the server I run the Bokeh server with:

```
bokeh serve bokehserver.py --port 5100 --host website.com:80
```

But when I visit website.com/plot/ I get a 404 from Bokeh and the servers terminal gives me: WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET / ("here was ip address") 3.04ms

I don't understand why it always gives a 404, or has it something to do with Nginx?

Thanks!

**Update 30/06**

Ok, I think I'm a step further, and hopefully in the good direction.
My p-website.conf now looks like:

```
server {
listen   80 default_server;
server_name  website.com;
client_max_body_size 25M;
access_log  /var/www/logs/p-website.access.nginx.log;
error_log  /var/www/logs/p-website.error.nginx.log error;
root    /var/www/pydocs/magnify/production/src;

include global/restrictions.conf;


location / {
    allow 127.0.0.1:5100
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5100;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_buffering off;
}

}
```

I now run the server with:

```
bokeh serve bokehserver.py --port 5100 --host 127.0.0.1:80
```

Now I don't get the 404 any more, but a "403: Forbidden" when I go to website.com:5100/bokehserver/. And this message on in the bokehserver terminal:

```
INFO:bokeh.server.tornado:Rejected connection from host 'website.com:5100' because it is not in the --host whitelist
WARNING:tornado.access:403 GET /bokehserver/ (213.152.161.35) 0.78ms
```

I tried to fix the whitelist problem by adding `allow 127.0.0.1:5100` in the p-website.conf, no luck.

Comment: Bokeh server have a default (but configurable) URL prefix `"app"`. Can you see the page at `website.com/plot/app/` ?

Comment: I get the same 404 in the browser: "404: Not Found"
And the same message in the terminal: "WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /plot/app/ ("here was ip address") 0.58ms"

Comment: What's in the nginx logs? Are nginx and bokeh server on different machines? Perhaps there is something blocking the traffic in between your nginx and the bokeh server. Is it possible to try them on the same machine with a `127.0.0.1` address instead of `websote.com` just to get a data point?

Comment: error.nginx.log is empty and in the access.nginx.log there are only the 404 GET requests, not the 403 (see update above): 
_"GET /bokehserver HTTP/1.1" 404 1037 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"_
They run on the same machine (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS )

Comment: You shouldn't navigate to `website.com:5100/bokehserver`, that tries to connect *directly* to the Bokeh server, bypassing nginx (on port 80) which you probably do not want to allow (and why it is rejecting you). You want to hit nginx, so you should just navigate to `website.com/bokehserver` (or more likely: `website.com/app/bokehserver`  and let nginx forward the connection internally.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info, so that was not the way to go. If I use the original p-website.conf settings and I go to: website.com/app/bokehserver I'm back at the origninal problem: the Bokeh "404: Not Found"

Comment: with your *original* conf, wouldn't it be `website.com/plot/app/bokehserver`?  Your orignal location block for the server is `/plot`, not `/`

Comment: True, but `website.com/plot/app/bokehserver` also gives the same Bokeh "404: Not Found" The same for `/plot/` or `/plot/app/`

Comment: That's not going to provide any thing useful, all the relevant information is in the logs, etc. How about take a step back. Does this exact coniguration work for you: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#nginx that is the exact configuration I used and tested when I wrote those docs. If that works I'd suggesrt moving forward by making incremental changes from that config, to see what step might be causing problems. I'm not actually and NGinx expert, and this is more of an NiGInx config question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out, apparently you need to add --prefix= with same location to the Bokeh command:

```
bokeh serve bokehserver.py --port 5100 --prefix=/plot/ --host website.com:80
```

And the location block in p-website.conf will look like:

```
location /plot/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5100;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_buffering off;
}
```

Comment: Note that the `--host` option is now deprecated and will return an unknown argument error.