# Bokeh websockets not connecting using nginx rewrite

Tags: python, nginx, bokeh

I am trying to run a bokeh server where I require the nginx path rewritten. The websocket connection works without the rewrite statement, but not with one. I get the error:

> Bokeh: Failed to connect to Bokeh server Error: Could not open websocket

On my Chrome console. Here's my sample `nginx` config:

```
location /somepath/myapp {

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    rewrite /somepath(.*) $1  break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5006;
}
```

Comment: What is in your `nginx` access log?

Comment: "GET /myapp/ws?bokeh-protocol-version=1.0&bokeh-session-id=jHFxd35cU5L3qGwfTQPE348S4doCAllV7URDozKgxBCl HTTP/1.1" 404 564 0.000 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36" "- - -" "80". When I try without the rewrite, I get a 101 instead of the 404

Comment: Actually we probably need the line before this one. Your application is breaking out of your imposed `/somepath` subdirectory, which is not necessarily anything that `nginx` can help you with. It may be fixable with a `proxy_redirect`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) for details.

Comment: The line before is `GET /somepath/myapp HTTP/1.1" 200`, with the rewrite statement and `GET /myapp HTTP/1.1" 200` without the rewrite statement. It's only the `/myapp/ws` with the rewrite statement that's causing the 404. I also tried adding `proxy_redirect off` and `proxy_redirect default`, but getting same error. Is there a specific proxy-redirect I should try?

Comment: Although this isn't what I am looking for, I am going ahead temporarily with it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38081389/bokeh-server-reverse-proxying-with-nginx-gives-404